# How to get host of current URL if using CDN?

Tags: ruby, url, sinatra

I am using various domain aliases through a CDN and I would like to return slightly different results depending on the domain alias. Is there a way to identify the domain of the current URL in Ruby?

For example, the origin URL of my website is `non-cdn.herokuapp.com`. There is a CDN which is caching that origin URL at `123.cloudfront.net`. There are 2 custom domains which are using CNAMEs to point to that CDN URL, `cdn-url1.com` and `cdn-url2.com`. When someone visits `cdn-url1.com`, `request.host` returns `non-cdn.herokuapp.com` rather than `cdn-url1.com`.

I know that I can return the true domain via Javascript, but can I determine it in Ruby?

Comment: If it was an DNS alias, you should be getting the correct URL. If you are using a _proxy_ though (e.g. a load balancer), then you'd be getting the URL of the proxy's request to your app. Can you confirm your setup?

Comment: I have an origin URL (which in this example is non-cdn.herokuapp.com). I am then using a CDN which is caching that origin URL (let's say that is 123.cloudfront.net). I then have 2 custom domains which are using CNAMEs to point to that CDN URL (which in this example are cdn-url1.com and cdn-url2.com). When someone visits cdn-url1.com, request.host returns non-cdn.herokuapp.com. Is there a way for it to return cdn-url1.com?

Comment: I understand the question, but... I'm saying this should not be happening. Sinatra gets the host name from the request header (either `HTTP_HOST` or `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST`). So if the client requested `cdn-url2.com`, then that's what Sinatra sees. The only way it could see something else is if there was another server on `cdn-url1.com` that contacted `non-cdn.herokuapp.com` and forwarded your request, with intent to return the response as its own (i.e. a proxy), without setting the customary `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST` header. I can't figure out a scenario with CNAME alias, without a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Cloudfront is not forwarding the host header to the origin. Here is how to fix it:

> Note: This resolution applies to origins other than an Amazon Simple
>   Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket. If you're using an Amazon S3
>   origin, avoid whitelisting the host header. For more information, see
>   Selecting the Headers to Base Caching On.
>
> 1. Open the Amazon CloudFront console, and then choose your distribution.
> 2. Choose the Behaviors view, and then choose the path you are using.
> 3. Choose Edit.
> 4. For Cache Based on Selected Request Headers, choose Whitelist.
> 5. Under Whitelist Headers, choose Host from the column on the left, and then choose Add.
> 6. Choose Yes, Edit.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/configure-cloudfront-to-forward-headers/